Equality integrate controlled path respect controled path and controlled path respect rough path $\int_0^T Y_ud\mathbf{Z}_u=\int_0^T Y_udZ_u$
I'm stuck with a step of the proof of the lemma 6.3. of the Rough Path Theory Lecture Notes by Andrew L. Allan https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2021/fs/401-4611-21L/notes/RP_lecture_notes_Allan.pdf, using the following proposition
Lemma 6.3
Let X $= (X, \mathbb{X}) \in \mathcal{C}^\alpha$ be a rough path. Let $(Z,Z')$ be a controlled path, and let $\mathbf{Z} = (Z,\mathbb{Z})$ be the canonical rough path lift of $Z$, as defined in (6.2).
Let $(Y,Y') \in \mathcal{D}_Z^{2\alpha}$ be a controlled path with respect to $Z$. Then $(Y,Y'Z') \in \mathcal{D}_X^{2\alpha}$ is a controlled path with respect to $X$, and, moreover, we have that
$$
\int_0^t Y_u d\mathbf{Z}_u = \int_0^t Y_u dZ_u,
$$
where on the left-hand side we have the rough integral of $(Y,Y')$ against $\mathbf{Z}$, and on the right-hand side we have the integral of $(Y,Y'Z')$ against $(Z, Z')$ as defined in Proposition 6.1.
Proof:
We have that
$$
Z_{s,t} = Z'_s X_{s,t} + R^Z_{s,t} \quad \text{and} \quad Y_{s,t} = Y'_s Z_{s,t} + R^Y_{s,t}.
$$
Thus,
$$
Y_{s,t} - Y'_s Z_{s,t} = Y_{s,t} - Y'_s (Z'_s X_{s,t} + R^Z_{s,t}) = R^Y_{s,t} + Y'_s R^Z_{s,t}.
$$
Since the right-hand side is $2\alpha$-Hölder continuous, we see that $(Y, Y'Z') \in \mathcal{D}_X^{2\alpha}$.
Similarly to the proof of Proposition 6.2, using the estimates in (5.9) and (6.1), we have
$$
\int_s^t Y_u d\mathbf{Z}_u = Y_s Z_{s,t} + Y'_s \mathbb{Z}_{s,t} + O(|t - s|^{3\alpha}),
$$
which implies
$$
\int_s^t Y_u dZ_u = Y_s Z_{s,t} + Y'_s Z'_s \mathbb{X}_{s,t} + O(|t - s|^{3\alpha}) = \int_s^t Y_u dZ_u + O(|t - s|^{3\alpha}).
$$
Taking $\lim_{|\pi| \to 0} \sum_{[s,t] \in \pi}$ on both sides, we obtain
$$
\int_0^T Y_u d\mathbf{Z}_u = \int_0^T Y_u dZ_u.
$$
$\square$
In the last step i couldn't see an analytic proof of $Y'_s\mathbb{Z}_{s,t}=Y'_sZ'_sZ'_s\mathbb{X}_{s,t}$.
My attempt $\mathbb{Z}_{s,t}=\int Z_s dZ_{s,t}=Z_{s}Z_{s,t}+Z'_{s}Z'_{s}\mathbb{Z}_{s,t}+O(|t-s|^{3\alpha})$ then $Y'_{s}\mathbb{Z}_{s,t}=Y'_{s}Z_{s}Z_{s,t}+Y'_{s}Z'_{s}Z'_{s}\mathbb{Z}_{s,t}+O(|t-s|^{3\alpha})$
But i don't know how to delete $Y'_{s}Z_{s}Z_{s,t}$, could someone help me.



Proposition
Description




Proposition 5.11
Let $\alpha \in \left( \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2} \right]$ and let X $= (X, \mathbb{X}) \in \mathcal{C}^\alpha([0,T];\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a rough path. Let $(Y, Y') \in \mathcal{D}_X^{2\alpha}([0,T]; \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}^m))$ be a controlled path and let $R^Y$ be the corresponding remainder term. Then the limit $$ \int_0^t Y_u d\mathbf{X}_u := \lim_{|\pi| \to 0} \sum_{[u,v] \in \pi} Y_u X_{u,v} + Y'_u \mathbb{X}_{u,v} $$ exists for every $t \in [0,T]$, where the limit is taken over any sequence of partitions $\pi$ of the interval $[0,t]$ with mesh size $|\pi| \to 0$. This limit is called the rough integral of $(Y,Y')$ against X, which moreover comes with the estimate $$ \left| \int_s^t Y_u d\mathbf{X}_u - Y_s X_{s,t} - Y'_s \mathbb{X}_{s,t} \right| \leq C \left( \|R^Y \|_{\alpha} \|X \|_{\alpha} + \|Y' \|_{\alpha} \|\mathbb{X} \|_{2\alpha} \right) |t - s|^{3\alpha} $$ for all $(s,t) \in \Delta[0,T]$, where the constant $C$ depends only on $\alpha$.


Proposition 6.1
Let X $= (X, \mathbb{X}) \in \mathcal{C}^\alpha$ be a rough path, and let $(Y,Y')$, $(Z,Z') \in \mathcal{D}_X^{2\alpha}$ be two controlled paths with remainders $R^Y$ and $R^Z$ respectively. Then the limit $$ \int_0^t Y_u dZ_u := \lim_{|\pi| \to 0} \sum_{[u,v] \in \pi} Y_u Z_{u,v} + Y'_u Z'_u \mathbb{X}_{u,v} $$ exists for every $t \in [0,T]$, where the limit is taken over any sequence of partitions $\pi$ of the interval $[0,t]$ with mesh size $|\pi| \to 0$. Moreover, we have the estimate $$ \left| \int_s^t Y_u dZ_u - Y_s Z_{s,t} - Y'_s Z'_s \mathbb{X}_{s,t} \right| \leq C \left( \|Y' \|_{\alpha} \|Z' \|_{\alpha} \|\mathbb{X} \|_{2\alpha}^2 + \|Y' \|_{\alpha} \|R^Z \|_{2\alpha} + \|R^Y \|_{\alpha} \|Z' \|_{\alpha} \|\mathbb{X} \|_{2\alpha} + \|R^Y \|_{\alpha} \|R^Z \|_{\alpha} \right) |t - s|^{3\alpha} $$ for all $(s,t) \in \Delta[0,T]$, where the constant $C$ depends only on $\alpha$.




Hey @Pastel Malcor, please don't forget to mark the question as answered!

Notice that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}_{s,t} :=& \int_s^t Z_{s,u} dZ_u = \int_s^t Z_u dZ_u - Z_s Z_{s,t} \\ 
=& Z_s Z_{s,t} + Z'_s Z_s' \mathbb{X}_{s,t} - Z_s Z_{s,t} + O(|t-s|^{3\alpha}) \\
=& Z'_s Z_s' \mathbb{X}_{s,t}  + O(|t-s|^{3\alpha}),
\end{align*}
where the second line follows from Proposition 6.1. Substitute the last line in the original expression and the proof follows.

Thank you, it's so clear
